# Redmine Project Repository Location

Tags: windows, git, redmine

I have redmine set up using bitnami on windows I created a project and added a repository by location successfully. Now I'm trying to clone this via redmine,

ex

```
git clone http://localhost/git/myproject

 or

git clone http://localhost/redmine/git/myproject
```

The repository of the project is located in the htdocs\git\myproject folder, but when I try this it says repo not found. What is the link for redmine repos, or do I have to move the local repo elsewhere on the server to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about git, but for Mercurial you need to insert the local path of the repository. It looks like that also the case for git. So you'll need to set the repository to /htdocs/git/myproject

Comment: tried apache2/htdocs/git/myproject and redmine/htdocs/git/myproject

no dice

Comment: Does your redmine user have access to that folder? (and doesn't it need to start with a / ?

Comment: i dont get an opportunity to enter a user/pass. it goes straight to not found